# Preventing loading dll in working directory, InvalidCastException Type A cannot be cast to Type B

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, appdomain

Is it possible to prevent the loading of a dll that is in the working directory and force it to use a dll somewhere else that I specify?

I am trying to run some unit tests and am getting this InvalidCast exception:

> [A]AssemblyA.DataType cannot be cast to [B]AssemblyA.DataType. Type A
>   originates from 'AssemblyA, Version=1.0.4645.21698, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location
>   'E:\webservice\bin\AssemblyA\AssemblyA.dll'. Type B originates from
>   'AssemblyA, Version=1.0.4645.21698, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'E:\TestResults\Out\AssemblyA.dll'.

On test startup, it calls some initialization code that uses Assembly.LoadFrom to load a dll from E:\webservice\bin\AssemblyA\AssemblyA.dll and create some of the types and put them in a cache.

There are post build events that xcopy the dlls to that location, so they are exactly the same dll in both locations.

But the unit test is running from the working directory of E:\testresults\out\ so it automatically loads the AssemblyA.dll there, ignoring the assembly already loaded, without ever giving me a chance to intercept that load with the Appdomain.AssemblyResolve event

So when the unit test code tries to retrieve an object from the cache that was put there from the E:\webservice\bin\AssemblyA\AssemblyA.dll it says invalid cast because its expecting the type from E:\TestResults\Out\AssemblyA.dll

After looking over [Best Practices for Assembly Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it seems like there is no way to  prevent it from loading the dll from the working directory, even though I already manually loaded the dll I want to use. Are there any options besides changing the application to not load from E:\webservice\bin... at all?

(Using LoadFile or Load byte[] both also result in the same error)

Comment: I don't understand why you referencing an assembly, that is not correctly? By the way: you can not turn off the default loading behavior of the CLR.

Comment: That is simply the existing architecture of the system, it was setup this way to allow the loading of different versions of weak named dlls that are in different subfolders. There are probably better ways to achieve that same result, but I am stuck with how it is for now. It previously didn't have any unit tests, so this was never an issue.

Comment: I suggest to write diffrent unit tests. A `test projectA` is referencing `assemblyA` and test it. Another `test projectB` is referencing and testing `assemblyB`. Is this a idea?

Comment: The problem is that there is shared code that both assemblyA and assemblyB reference, that shared code is what is doing the LoadFrom of the dll from another location instead of using the dll in the working directory

Comment: The way that System.AddIn is dealing with this problem is to forbid CopyLocal=true on the reference assembly. This way is it loaded only by a call to LoadFrom and not by the CLR assembly loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Panos suggested in the comment above, this was solved by setting CopyLocal=false on the referenced assemblies. That way the CLR can't attempt to load the dll from the working directory because the dll isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

Now, I try to help you out of you problem..

I recommended to sign your assembly with a [StrongName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k50fs3b.aspx).

The CLR use this to identify the assembly. This is not almost solving your problem.
But to solve your problem I suggest to use an interface to encapsulate your diffrent types. So, You can store any type in your cache and return only the intrerface, and the cast is gone.

If this is not solving your problem, you must provide me more information.

Comment: That is a good idea to improve the system eventually, for right now I will just rewrite the code that I am testing so that it doesn't interact with the types loaded from the other assembly. So it will still have the two assemblies loaded, but they won't interact causing the InvalidCastException